# Integrating nuclio with GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mlrun, nuclio

I have been following the below mentioned documentation - https://nuclio.io/docs/latest/setup/gke/getting-started-gke/

There, the step is to - Create the RBAC roles that are required for using Nuclio: To do so, the command is mentioned to install nuclio-rbac.yaml from the github link provided i.e., https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuclio/nuclio/master/hack/k8s/resources/nuclio-rbac.yaml . But, the file does not exist as the github provided got updated 3 weeks back and the documentation nuclio is not updated yet.

Can someone please help me with it? And explain me the process for integrating nuclio with gcp.

Comment: I mentioned your question in Slack 'Nuclio', it can help.

Answer (score 1):

The Nuclio doc site got updated recently and can now be found [here](https://docs.nuclio.io/en/stable/contents.html).
Specifically, refer to [installing Nuclio on GCP](https://docs.nuclio.io/en/stable/setup/gke/getting-started-gke.html).

The RBAC configuration (roles and rolebindings) in the Github repository is available in [the templates directory](https://github.com/nuclio/nuclio/tree/master/hack/k8s/helm/nuclio/templates), but installing Nuclio using Helm (as in the above documentation) should handle it all by itself.